# Problem when writing decimal data as string on the blockchain

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, storage

I'm trying to develop a dApp that uses smart contracts to write decimal data in a CSV file on the blockchain.

What I'm working with currently is the following:

1. Convert the CSV file into JSON string format.
2. write this JSON string to the blockchain to store it.

here is my smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract DatasetHandler{

  struct DataFile{
    uint id;
    string name;
    string dataset;
  }

  mapping(uint => DataFile) public DataFiles;

  uint public dCount;

  function addDataset(string memory _name, string memory _dataset) public{
    dCount ++;
    DataFiles[dCount] = DataFile(dCount,_name, _dataset);
  }

   function readDataset(uint _id) public view returns(string memory){
     DataFile memory _dataset = DataFiles[_id];
     return _dataset.dataset;
  }

}
```

the code above is a simple contract for writing and reading the dataset.
it has been working fine with all kinds of data types, strings numbers ..
however, I tried to store a JSON string that included decimal numbers in it, like this for example:

```
[{"BMI": "43.4","age": "33"}]
```

And it's giving me errors and won't save.
I know ethereum VM still has limitations regarding decimal numbers but I thought that storing these values as a string wouldn't be a problem.
I have been stuck on this problem for days, and I hope someone gives a solution or a hint of what I should do..

I don't know if this is related but I use remix to compile and deploy smart contracts to my local test blockchain, Ganache. And I use web3.py to communicate with ganache.

here are the exception errors I'm getting:

```
File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1371, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 280, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 447, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8545): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\miss-\Desktop\ether.example\app.py", line 29, in <module>
    datasetHandeler.functions.addDataset(name, dataset).transact()
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 999, in transact
    return transact_with_contract_function(
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1592, in transact_with_contract_function
    txn_hash = web3.eth.send_transaction(transact_transaction)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 695, in send_transaction
    return self._send_transaction(transaction)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 186, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 147, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 89, in middleware
    return make_request(method, (transaction,))
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 37, in middleware
    hex(get_buffered_gas_estimate(web3, transaction)),
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 148, in get_buffered_gas_estimate
    gas_estimate = web3.eth.estimate_gas(gas_estimate_transaction)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 735, in estimate_gas
    return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 186, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 147, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz\functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\middleware\exception_retry_request.py", line 105, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\web3\_utils\request.py", line 48, in make_post_request
    response = session.post(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 590, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\miss-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8545): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

Comment: From the contract's (and EVM's) point of view, those are just strings. It doesn't understand or parse the contents. Therefore you can have whatever contents there - the error must be somewhere else

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, I tried to remove the decimal points from the CSV and ran the code again and this time everything was fine. So I'm still not sure..

Comment: Well, paste the error and the code that causes it

Comment: I have updated the question and pasted the errors I'm getting. I'm calling the contract in an app.py file by  datasetHandeler.functions.addDataset(name, dataset).transact()